# iphone login view, how to reload controller

Tags: iphone, authentication, reload, viewdidload, loginview

I am working on an application with a LoginViewController and a TabBarViewcontroller.

When the application is ran, I add the LoginViewController as a subView of window in the delegate.
Once the login is ok, I remove the LoginViewController (removeFromSuperView) and add the TabBarViewController instead as a subview of windows.

This works fine.

In one of the tab of the TabBar I have a view containing a button to disconnect the user.
When clicking on the button it performs the opposite than what described above:
- remove the TabBarViewcontroller from the superView
- add the loginViewController instead.

This works also fine except for 2 things:

- when I login again, I get directly on the last tab I used (the one with the disconnect button) when I'd like to get to the first one
- If I login with another user, the TabBarController is not refreshed (I see the data of the previous user... kind of dangerous:) ).

Well, those 2 things seems to be related to the same problem, the TabBarViewController is not unloaded and reloaded.
Could you please help on how to do this ?

Thanks a lot,
Luc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should release your tabBarController when disconnecting and allocate it when connecting.

Comment: Hello, is there any problem to perform this action even if the tabBarcontroller was first allocated in IB ?

Comment: You may have to re-wire your outlets programmaticaly

Comment: ok, but I mean I still initilize it in IB at first place ? and then de-allocate and re-allocate when I need it ?

Comment: Yes you can do it that way or instantiate it programmatically.

Comment: how would you do it programmatically (I left this problem for some times but really need to figure out how to do know) :)

Comment: @Luc Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @OhhMee, I'm currently using another way of handling welcome / login / main views. I've described this in https://gist.github.com/1744267 (there is a reference to the article I used). Please let me know if you manage to have that working.

Answer (score 0):

I post an NSNotification to solve this problem, your view controller can observe this and reload the tabController as needed.